# Changing python selenium webdriver's zoom breaks the click function?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Every time I try to load the page zoomed out, the elements I want the program to click no longer are clicked and it gives an ElementClickInterceptedException saying it was trying to click on a different element. I've tested different zooms, same result. It's almost like it's just using the elements' X and Y coords for the normal zoom page even though I changed the zoom for it (i.e. if an element was close to the footer and I zoomed out, it would click the element right below it, where it was previously located). I would think that it shouldn't matter where on the page an element was located as long as I used find_element_by whatever but here I am. Anyone know a fix? Here is how I loaded a site and zoomed out:

```
driver.get(website)
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")
```

Here is the click that throws the error:

```
ch = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.changeplayer.form-control.ui-autocomplete-input')
ch.click()
```

Comment: Could you add your click function? This is the par that is failing right?

Comment: @Jortega I edited it

Comment: Just to confirm if you comment out `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")` everything works fine?

Comment: @Jortega that is correct

Answer (score 3):

1. **This has been a known issue for a long time.** ChromeDriver doesn't effectively support for clicking with zooming. [It has been an issue since 2013 and there does not appear to be a fix in the works.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628)
2. `It's almost like it's just using the elements' X and Y coords` in a way, yes. The zoom alters the offsets so that ChromeDriver isn't correctly targeting the right part of the page.